# Powershell array "-contains = true"...but get the index

Tags: xml, powershell

I wonder if somebody could provide me with an answer to probably an easy question.

I have an array of string objects and I am checking this array for specific values using the **contains** parameter.

If the result is true, I need to find the index so I can access the other properties.

```
$xml.STORE_ITEMS.Product -contains "SNS-01"
```

The result is **true**  but now I need to know the index so I can go back and check another property such as stock level.

Comment: If you want to enumerate the rest of the array you could do `$xml.STORE_ITEMS.Product | Where-Object {$_ -ne  "SNS-01"}`

Comment: You could perhaps use the array `IndexOf` method like `($xml.STORE_ITEMS.Product).IndexOf("SNS-01")`. This returns the 0-based index of an array or `-1` if not found. Mind you, this is case-sensitive.

Comment: I would make a hashtable from it.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the input XML? There are much more efficient ways to navigate an XML document

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml.STORE_ITEMS | where Product -eq SNS-01
```

Or assuming Product is a node.  If it's an attribute, it would be "@Product".  Namespaces would complicate this.

```
select-xml '//STORE_ITEMS[Product="SNS-01"]' file.xml | % node
```